# Legends on R Leaflet Maps

Tags: r, leaflet

While I realize that putting legends on maps using the Rstudio [`leaflet` package](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) is still a work in progress, I've been trying to add a legend *post-hoc* to the HTML that R generates.

```
library("leaflet")
set.seed(100)
pdf <- data.frame(Latitude = runif(100, -90,90), Longitude = runif(100, -180,180), 
                  col=rep(c("red", "blue"), 50 ))

#just red
leaflet(pdf) %>% addTiles()  %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = ~ Latitude, lng = ~ Longitude, color= ~col)
```

I've been trying to adapt the code from http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html and figure out where to add it to the output from running the above code in R and turning it into HTML.

So something like putting the following in the body of the html:

```
<script>
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [red, blue],
        labels = [];

    // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each label
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
            grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
    }

    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);
<script>
```

This doesn't seem to work, however. Nothing pops up. Nor is it clear how I would use names other than 'red', and 'blue' for the grades, as it were. I've also added in CSS as shown in the choropleth example as well, but no dice.

Has anyone done this - manually added a legend to their R output (say, grabbing the source from Rpubs after publishing) to add a legend?

Comment: Note the package is written by the RStudio people, but its just plain R otherwise.

Comment: Yes - I said the Rstudio leaflet package to differentiate it from other R packages that generate leaflet code.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not quite what I was looking for, it appears that an addLegend function is on its way, and is in one branch of the package. See some documentation and and an example here:

http://smartinsightsfromdata.github.io//2015/04/25/choropleths.html

Comment: [This link](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html) lead to the documentation about legends